# How do I perform a formula on a column in numpy

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d ndarray that I need to convert each column to a list.

I have posted 2 code snippets below one which only gets me the first cell and the second one which gets me the first occurrence in the 2d array
my array looks like this:

````
 ```
 [[ 2.29  0.09]
 [ 7.12  1.2 ]
 [ 6.53  0.  ]
 [ 8.79  2.12]
 [ 2.51  0.  ]]
 ```
````

I have tried this:
    
    `tmp_lst = np.array(cne_arr[0,0]).tolist()`

and this
    
    `np.array(cne_arr[0]).tolist()`

The first code from above  gets me the first column of the first row:2.29

and the second gets me the entire first row: 2.29  0.09

```
i need 2 lists one that is the first column
  (2.29 7.12 6.53 8.79 2.51 )

and one that is the second column
  (0.09 1.2 0.  2.12 0.)
```

I am sure here must be an easy way but I am new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try

```
tmp = # the array 
col_1 = tmp[:, 0].tolist()
col_2 = tmp[:, 1].tolist()
```